# Collecting geolocation data that complies with COPPA

Tags: android, geolocation, location

[Children's Online Privacy Protection Act (COPPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children's_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act) is a United States federal law. One of the things that trigger a COPPA obligation is:

> When the geolocation data is sufficient to allow a person to identify
>   the street name and city or town a child is in.

**What can I do to assure that the geolocation data my app is collecting is not sufficient to allow a person to identify a street name and city?**

Using COARSE_LOCATION obfuscate the location to a block level, but that isn't enough.

What I am currently doing is adding a random error to locations, but it isn't a good solution and it leads to other kind of problems.

Any ideas? Anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about COPPA compliance and not about programming

Comment: I don't think it is off topic. The question is about geolocation, COPPA is only mentioned to give more context to the question

Answer (score 1):

Even just asking the ZIP code is considered to be a breach of COPPA, so I'm afraid that even a COARSE_LOCATION would be against the rule.  For that matter, there are a whole lot of new things in the new version of COPPA that you may not collect from kids under 13 including an IP Address or any cookie.

Does your Android app target kids under 13 specifically?  If not, you might consider using an age gate and only collecting geolocation data from those who self-identify themselves as being 13 or older.

Have you considered getting verified parental consent first?  Once a parent or guardian has signed off on what you plan to collect, you may grab any Personally Identifiable Information from a child under 12 you want to. There are a few services out there that could actually help you with this now.  AgeCheq is free to developers, and Asertid has just been purchased by TrustE.

Comment: Actually, is not an app, but a library. And it will be used in apps targeted to kids. So the parental consent is not on my hands. I do have a setting to let the library know if it should comply with COPPA or not.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan.  Consider taking a look at AgeCheq and Assertid anyway, though.  You can sign up for a services account in 60 seconds and offer it to your customers as a way for them to inform parents about what Personally Identifiable Information their app collects.  https://services.agecheq.com  http://www.assertid.com/operators/